# Why is the data in the PDF written in the 1st column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tabula-py

I have a pdf file called Question.pdf, and its content is as follows.

[Question.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfx0a.png)

I am converting my pdf file to an xlsx file using the python tabula module. However, it writes all the data in the 1st column of my excel file, how can I delete this field? (the part indicated in the red area)

[data.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVZwn.png)

```py
import tabula
df = tabula.read_pdf('Question.pdf', pages=1, lattice=True)[1]

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\r', ' ')
data = df.dropna()
data.to_excel('data.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this while exporting;

```
data.to_excel('data.xlsx', index=False, header=None)
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: Glad to Help... Drop a like or accept the best answer that works... To grow & motivate community... Happy Coding :)